# What permissions do I need if IIS Manager is blank or empty?

Tags: iis-7

**Problem**

[image]

**Attempted Solutions**

I added my account in AD to the groups Administrators, Domain Admins, Domain Users, IIS_Users.

[image]

IIS was missing the icons in red in the management section

[image]

so I ran the IIS Manager as administrator, entered the credentials of a domain account frequently used to install software and added the management service to get those icons.

[image]

I then added myself to the server and to the sites but for my account IIS Manager still looks like the first screenshot.

[image]

What permission setting could I still be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try right-click on **"Start Page"**, and then **"Connect to server"**, type in your server's name/IP. I think you have just somehow deleted the connection to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to Open IIS Manager "run as administrator"

OR

User should be member of IIS Group.

During the setting you need to run gpupdate /force to update the changes.

Thanks